# dig not working in a virtual host environment

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, dns

I have installed three virtual machines (RHEL 6) on virtualbox, and attached a bridged mode network to all machines

i have to use my first machine to be a DNS and the second and third machine should get their ip from the DNS (i dont need DHCP). is it possible?

i have installed bind in my first machine and added the following in named.conf

```
options {
         listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 192.168.0.254; };
         listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1;};
         directory "/var/named";
         dump-file "/var/named/data/cache_dumb.db";
         statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
         memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
         allow-query { localhost; };
         recursion yes;
         dnssec-enable yes;
         dnssec-validation yes;
         dnssec-lookaside auto;
         bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
        file "data/named.run";
        severity dynamic;
        };
};
zone "." IN {
         type hint;
         file "named.ca";
};
include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zone";

zone "example.com" IN {
         type master;
         file "example.com.zone";
         allow-update { none; };
};
```

i have added following to the /var/named/example.com.zone

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
$TTL 1D
@             IN    SOA    instructor.example.com. root.example.com. (
                    201408181847   ; serial number
                    6H             ;refersh after 6 hour
                    1H             ;retry after 1 hour
                    1W             ;expire after 1 week
                    1D)            ; minimum TTL of 1 day
;
;
              IN    NS    instructor.example.com.
              IN    NS    desktop1.example.com.
              IN    NS    desktop2.example.com.
instructor    IN    A    192.168.0.254
desktop1      IN    A    192.168.0.1
desktop2      IN    A    192.168.0.2
;
;
@             IN    MX 10 mail.example.com.
mail          IN    A    192.168.0.253
;
;
```

after that i checked using named-checkconf and no error were returned
then i started named service

```
service named start
chkconfig named on
```

after that i configured my ip in device configuration as

```
static IP 192.168.0.254
Netmask   255.255.255.0
Default gateway 192.168.0.254
primary DNS     192.168.0.254
```

and DNS configuration as

```
hostname istructor.example.com
primary DNS 192.168.0.254
DNS search path   example.com
```

and restarted the network
i could dig all hosts from this machine

then i logged on to second machine (first machine still running) and set ip in device configuration as

```
static IP 192.168.0.1
Netmask   255.255.255.0
Default gateway 192.168.0.254
primary DNS     192.168.0.254
```

and DNS configuration as

```
hostname desktop1.example.com
primary DNS 192.168.0.254
DNS search path   example.com
```

and restarted network
now when i dig desktop1.example.com i got the error

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3-P3-RedHat-9.7.3-8.P3.e16 <<>> desktop1.example.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

what could be the problem...

please help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From second machine, try this:

> ping 192.168.0.254

Do you get a response?  If not, basic networking is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ya its pinging...
I sorted out the problem.. It was the iptables making the problem...
I added
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW --dport 53 -j ACCEPT

And reatarted iptables.

Now its working like a charm.. :)